# Is there an expression that will eliminate decimal places and display if value is null? SSRS 2012 Report Builder 3.0

Tags: reporting-services, iif

I am creating a report and the data for this field displays as "14.00000" and I need it to be a whole value "14".  When I use the FormatNumber functionality, I receive an error when there is no value in this block.

```
=FormatNumber(IIF(Fields!quantity.Value IS Nothing,"", Fields!quantity.Value),0)
=FormatNumber(IIF(Fields!quantity.Value IS "","", Fields!quantity.Value),0)
=IIF(Fields!quantity.Value IS "","", Fields!quantity.Value)
```

This expression works without the Error, but it does not format the field down to "14".

I have tried using the internal limit on decimal places for the field and it does not appear to do anything.

```
=IIF(Fields!quantity.Value IS "","", Fields!quantity.Value)
```

displays blank if there is no value, but if there is a value it displays with "14.0000"

I would like the field to only display the whole number value "14" if a value exists and be blank if there is no value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could probably be solved by simply converting the value to an integer.  Try adding a `CInt(..)` to your expression like the following:

```
=IIF(Fields!quantity.Value IS "" OrElse IsNothing(Fields!quantity.Value),"", CInt(Fields!quantity.Value))
```

This should convert whatever is left in the `quantity` field to an integer which should remove any decimals and allow further formatting if necessary.  I'm guessing that the `14.0000` is a string datatype -- SSRS can't format strings with numeric formatting.

Comment: This was very helpful, but it did not completely fix my problem.  The system would still show an !Error when the value was Null.  I was able to get the desired result with embedded code formatting in the Report Properties.

Comment: @BrianPayne The other alternative to checking for `NULL` values is to add a check for `IsNothing`.  Just add `OR IsNothing(Fields!quantity.Value)` to the conditional part of the expression.

Comment: You should really use `OrElse` rather than `OR` as SSRS doesn't short circuit by default.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the desired result with embedded code formatting in the Report Properties.

Function FormatQuantity(quantity AS String) AS String
If (quantity Is Nothing) Then
Return Nothing
Else
If (IsNumeric(quantity)) Then
Return Format(Convert.ToDouble(quantity), "###")
Else 
Return quantity 
End If
End If
End Function

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using an expression you can simply set `.Format` property to `f0` in order to eliminate decimal places and leave blank if there is no value.